# anagram solver not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

So, this has been my project for a long time, and eventually, I have made an anagram solver in python 3.4, except it's supposed to find anagram for the word + a random letter. I have worked out all the error messages, but there are no more errors, it just doesn't do it. All help appreciated. I have had a lot of helpful comments, but it is still not working. I have updated the code in the question.([Here](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt) is the file I used with all the words of the dictionary on different lines, it's really helpful and I had to look for something like this for months.)

```js
file = open("C:\\my stuff\\brit-a-z.txt","r")
def anagram(word):
    for alpha in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
        newletter = chr(alpha)
        for line in file:
            ref = line.strip()
            
            word1 = list(word)
            list.append(newletter)
            word1_list.sort()
            ref_list = list(line)
            ref_list.sort()
            if word1_list == ref_list:
                print(line)
while True:
    inp = input()
    anagram(inp)
```

.

Comment: Not the solution but you can use `newletter = chr(97+alpha)` instead of 26 if statements.

Comment: So it finds the anagrams of words + words with 1 letter off?

Comment: @serbia99 or something like `my_dict = dict(zip(range(1, len(string.ascii_lowercase) + 1), string.ascii_lowercase))`

Comment: @NChauhan Yes, it is. I think you mean 1 letter extra though. serbia and roganjosh thanks you for your help, but do you mind explaining what those do? I'm still new to python.

Comment: So 'dog' and 'god' would match as well as 'paint' and 'pant'?

Comment: No, only pant and paint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
with open("C:\\my_folders_are_in_here\\brit-a-z.txt", 'r') as f:
    check_list = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

def anagram(word):
    for alpha in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
        newletter = chr(alpha)
        for line in check_list:
            word1_list = list(word + newletter)
            word1_list.sort()
            ref_list = list(line)
            ref_list.sort()
            if word1_list == ref_list:
                print(line)

while True:
    inp = input()
    anagram(inp)
```

I took advantage of the `chr()` and `ord()` built-in function to remove the long if that converts `alpha` into `newletter`.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it's still now working.

Comment: Sorry I tested with a harcoded array. Updated to handle a file.

Answer (score 1):

Reading lines from file in Python also includes newline characters. 
So if one line in the file is the word `"the"` for example, assigning `ref = line`, `ref` will equal `"the\n"`(or `"the\r\n"`). Your sorted `ref_list` then becomes `['\n', 'e', 'h', 't']`

Reading from keyboard using `input()`, however, does not include newline characters. Your `word1_list` never contains a `'\n'`, thus, `word1_list` and  `ref_list` will never be equal.

Fix: change `ref = line` into `ref = line.strip()` to remove newline characters.